# Jest, Enzyme, React, Next.js, Typescript .default is not a constructor

Tags: reactjs, typescript, unit-testing, jestjs, next.js

I want to write simple test checking if my next.js page loads without errors.
I followed [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@mateuszsokola/configuring-react-16-jest-enzyme-typescript-7122e1a1e6e8) and I almost got it working, but [simple-react-validator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/simple-react-validator) stays in my way with the following error when i run `npm run test` which justs run `jest` behind the scene:

> TypeError: simple_react_validator_1.default is not a constructor

```
private validator : SimpleReactValidator = new SimpleReactValidator({
     |                                                ^
  96 |         locale: 'en',
  97 |         autoForceUpdate: this,
  98 |         validators: {
```

Before I couldn't even use simple-react-validator with my Typescript Next.js application. I needed to add to next-env.d.ts this:

`declare module 'simple-react-validator' {
  const content: any;
  export default content;
}`

Then I was able to use it in my application, but tests are complaining about constructor.

What can cause this issue? Maybe I need to somehow explicitly tell it somewhere what SimpleReactValidator is but I don't know where.

Answer (score 0):

After some time I figured it out.
If using typescript, you must to wrap your mock in 'default' property:

```
jest.mock('simple-react-validator', () => {
  return {
    'default': class SimpleReactValidatorMock {
      allValid() { return true; }
      fieldValid() { return true; }
      message() { return ''; }
    }
  }
});
```

I found the answer here:
https://github.com/kulshekhar/ts-jest/issues/120#issuecomment-283653644